# flex basis not applied when two divs containing the element

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have an input element which I want to grow and shrink using flex shrink but its flex-basis size is not being applied.

Here is my html:

```
<div class="flex-container">
    <div class="flex-row">
        <input type="text" name="query" class="searchbar" />
    </div>
<div>
```

and my css:

```
.flex-container{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.flex-row input { flex: 0 1 450px; }
```

why is the basis size not being applied? it is getting set to a much smaller width than 450px.

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/L4sqdjkd/2/) is a fiddle with the example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually what is happening here is that your input's immediate parent `.flex-row`  is a simple div with no css properties and also not set to be a flex container hence it's width is auto and wrapping around the input and not applying the flex properties. To apply flex properties to the input use the following css to make the input's parent display be flex.

```
.flex-container{
   display: flex;
 }

.flex-row {
    display: flex;
    flex:1;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.flex-container input { flex: 0 1 450px; }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! so if I have a flex container with many different rows to be flex display and to be growing and shrinking, then do i need to do something like .flex-container *{ display: flex} ? and why do I need flex: 1 for the flex-row?

Comment: You can use .flex-container > .flex-row {display:flex; flex:1; } to apply it to all the flex-row child divs within the flex-container. As to why we are setting flex:1 for the row so that the row will take all the free space around it's left and right and not wrap the inner content.